# R Custom Function - include argument value in title

Tags: r, function

I've written a basic custom function to produce some charts:

```
gw_chart <- function(variable) {
hist(variable, prob = T)
lines(density(variable, na.rm = T))
rug(jitter(variable))
qqPlot(variable, main = ("QQ-Plot"))
}
```

when I type `gw_chart(age)`, where age is a variable in a dataframe, the function produces two charts, but the title of the histogram is based on the default of `hist()`  --> "Histogram of variable", and the `xlabel` is variable.

How do I get the value of variable - in the case : age - to be displayed instead?

And I'd like to customise the title of the qqplot as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gw_chart <- function(variable) {

  lab <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  hist(variable, prob = T, main= paste("histogram of", lab))
  lines(density(variable, na.rm = T))
  rug(jitter(variable))
  qqPlot(variable, main= paste("QQplot of", lab))

 }
```